# Compute $\int_1^2 B_t \; dB_t$

Tags: stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

I have to compute the following Ito integral:
$$\int_1^2 B_t \; dB_t$$
where $(B_t)_{t \geq 0}$ is the 1-dimensional Brownian Motion.

In the definition of Ito integral, the integral is taken from $0$ to some $T$, i.e we have $\int_0^T$. But I have to calculate $\int_1^2 B_t \; dB_t$.

Can someone, please, explain me/give me a hint on how to calculate this integral?

Thank you!

Comment: $\int_1^2B_tdB_t = \int_0^2 B_tdB_t - \int_0^1 B_t dB_t$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

let $f(x)=x^2$ by application of Ito's lemma, we have 
$$f(B_t)=f(B_s)+\int_{s}^{t}f'(B_u)\,dB_u+\frac{1}{2}\int_{s}^{t}f''(B_u)du$$
as a result
$$B_t^2=B_s^2+2\int_{s}^{t}B_u\,dB_u+\int_{s}^{t}du$$
let $t=2$ and $s=1$, thus
$$B_t^2=B_s^2+2\int_{1}^{2}B_u\,dB_u+\int_{1}^{2}du$$
in the other words
$$\int_{1}^{2}B_u\,dB_u=\frac{B^2(2)-B^2(1)-1}{2}$$